# Gaming Motherboard for a Desktop Build

Tags: drivers, games, ubuntu-drivers, motherboard

**Statement:** I’d like to preface my question hoping it helps any of you to help me. In a nutshell, I’m fed up with Windows for a wide variety of reasons. Thus am intent of divorcing that OS. To that end, I plan a DIY gaming desktop build. I wanted a 17.3 desktop replacement, but so many are built to discourage you in whole or part from upgrading.  Except for Alienware, but in my experience, you can’t talk to them without being subjected to pressure sell and hoop-jumping. So I’m going for a desktop build. As for it being a gaming computer, I don’t play games. However, I like the RAM and GPU muscle (yes, I know, it’s overkill) I’d get for my adventures in animation, video editing, and photography work. Likely, I’ll be giving up a lot of cherished software on leaving Windows, but I’ve had it and am determined to leave the OS entirely.

**Question:** Can anyone direct me to a gaming motherboard that is Ubuntu/LINUX friendly including drivers for the MB?

Comment: "Drivers for the MB" are include with the Linux kernel. You rarely install drivers in Linux. Many of us here use multiple OS every day, so please dial back the Windows rancor. You are likely to find elements of Linux to be frustrating, too. Most common motherboards work just fine in Linux. Advice: Be sure to purchase from a reputable vendor with robust return policy.

Comment: Thank you for swift, forum advisory, and to the point response. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. Though I signed up a while ago, I haven't frequented this forum and somehow got the idea I could ask any Ubuntu related questions. I will avoid making that assumption henceforth. I came here because I wasn't get answers from MB manufacturers after a month of trying. My bad.